# How to create a boolean column depending on positive or negative values of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have dataframe with a column like this:

```
184         1
190        -2
272       -14
382       -40
439        20
440        20
797       -45
1108        0
1122       -1
1415       -1
1419        0
1641       -1
```

What i need to do is to create a boolean column which value will be 1 if the value in the row of the previous column is positive, or 0 if the value is negative.

the output column would be like:

```
1 1
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 1
```

and so on... The basic idea is that this column will correspond the other column considering if the value there is positive or negative.

How can i do this in pandas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `previous column is positive` you probably mean row

Comment: yes sorry. It's row wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df[, "new_col"] = np.where(df[,"old_col"]>0,1,0)
```

Comment: @Miguel2488 you sure this is what you need ? since this check the current row not previous row

Comment: this is it. I'm sorry, the explanation was as bit confusing

Answer (score 3):

```
df['mycolumn'] > 0
```

Gives you an array of True/False Values. You could just safe those directly:

```
df['is_positive'] = df['mycolumn'] > 0
```

Or you use `numpy.where(boolean_list, true_value, false_value)` which replaces in a boolean list the `True` values with `true_value` and the `False` Values with `false_value`.

```
df['is_positive'] = np.where(df['mycolumn'] > 0, 1, 0)
```